# How to create a semi transparent form in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have to develop a semi-transparent form in WPF, but controls should not be transparent.

I have tried different things like setting opacity=0.5 but no result.

- I know that AllowTransparency can be set to True only if WindowStyle set to None, but I need to show Border as well

**UPDATE:**
Pavlo Glazkov, What is your opinion for this solution

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Opacity="1" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Border Margin="2,2,12,34" Name="border1" BorderBrush="Lavender" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="20,0,20,0"></Border>
    <Button Height="23" Margin="93,101,110,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="CadetBlue" Foreground="White">Hello WPF</Button>
    <Button Height="24" Margin="0,8,20,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="21" Click="button2_Click">X</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Forms don't exist in WPF; are you referring to a Window...or something different?

Comment: Regarding "Pavlo Glazkov, What is your opinion for this solution"... Well, hard to say. It depends on your goal. If this kind of border is what you want then it is the way to go. The only thing is that in this case you have absolutely transparent window. You can actually click through it. If this isn't a desired behavior, you should set the background to a not completely transparent color.

Comment: @ Pavlo Glazkov - Well you are right, this type of answer is only temporary type solution. Basically I am surprised to see that MS has not provided this kind of feature in WPF. I know way back in 2005 some lengthy and complex code which uses APIs to achieve this kind of functionality, but it is 2011 and we still need to write lengthy code, its ugly. Well which colors you are talking about that are not completely transparent colors ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you need to set `AllowTransperency` to `True`. Then, you can set the background of the window to a transparent (to desired extent) brush:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackground}">
    <Window.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" 
                        Color="White"
                        Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

Please note that `AllowTransperency` can be set to `True` only if `WindowStyle` set to `None`.

**Update:**
If you don't want to set `WindowStyle` to `None` and would like to keep standart border and window buttons there is an alternative that will work only on Windows Vista/7 with Windows Aero theme.

The trick is that you can extend the "Glass" area to the whole window using the following code:

```
public static class WindowUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extends the glass area into the client area of the window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="window">Window to extend the glass on.</param>
    /// <param name="thikness">Thickness of border to extend.</param>
    public static void ExtendGlass(this Window window, Thickness thikness) {
        try {
            int isGlassEnabled = 0;
            Win32.DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref isGlassEnabled);
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5 && isGlassEnabled > 0) {
                // Get the window handle
                var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
                var mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);

                if (mainWindowSrc != null) {
                    if (mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget != null) {
                        mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
                    }

                    // Get the dpi of the screen
                    System.Drawing.Graphics desktop =
                        System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(mainWindowSrc.Handle);

                    float dpiX = desktop.DpiX / 96;
                    float dpiY = desktop.DpiY / 96;

                    // Set Margins
                    var margins = new MARGINS {
                        cxLeftWidth = (int)(thikness.Left * dpiX),
                        cxRightWidth = (int)(thikness.Right * dpiX),
                        cyBottomHeight = (int)(thikness.Bottom * dpiY),
                        cyTopHeight = (int)(thikness.Top * dpiY)
                    };

                    window.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

                    Win32.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(mainWindowSrc.Handle, ref margins);
                }
            }
            else {
                window.Background = SystemColors.WindowBrush;
            }
        }
        catch (DllNotFoundException) {

        }
    }
}

public class Win32
{
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
    public static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref int en);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);


    [DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "ClientToScreen", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, [In, Out] POINT pt);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MARGINS
{
    public int cxLeftWidth;
    public int cxRightWidth;
    public int cyTopHeight;
    public int cyBottomHeight;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class POINT
{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
}
```

To extend the glass to the whole window you need to call the ExtendGlass extension method in a SizeChanged event handler of the window and pass a `Thickness` that covers whole window:

```
public MyWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
}

private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    double horisontalThickness = Width / 2;
    double verticalThickness = Height / 2;

    var glassThickness = new Thickness(horisontalThickness, verticalThickness, horisontalThickness, verticalThickness);

    this.ExtendGlass(glassThickness);
}
```

Comment: I posted that, too, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem that controls should not be transparent. no idea how to do that.

Comment: Then you need to set the window background to a transparent color instead of setting the opacity of the window itself. I updated my post to show how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. •I know that AllowTransperency can be set to True only if WindowStyle set to None, but I need to show Border as well

Comment: Then you have to create one yourself.

Comment: OK, do you need custom transparency settings? I can show you how you can make you window semi-transparent using Windows Vista/7 glass effect.

Comment: Pavlo Glazkov, I have edited my post, look and tell me your opinion

Comment: @ Pavlo Glazkov - Well you are right, this type of answer is only temporary type solution. Basically I am surprised to see that MS has not provided this kind of feature in WPF. I know way back in 2005 some lengthy and complex code which uses APIs to achieve this kind of functionality, but it is 2011 and we still need to write lengthy code, its ugly. Well which colors you are talking about that are not completely transparent colors ?

Comment: That is probably because the functionality you need is very rare. And still WPF provides very powerful capabilities to customize look'n'feel of applications. Anyway, regarding not transparent colors see my answer. Basically, you need to define a brush with opacity > 0 and use it as a background of your window.

Comment: @Pavlo Glazkov - In the end with your help I have achieved my gaol. You are a gem. Thanks for be patient with me. Bye :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFGlass.aspx), it will create a Glass Background for your Window (looks like the Vista and Windows7 transparency effect)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx) is some further explanation from Microsoft.